# What produces more crema?

Tags: espresso, brewing-process, crema

1. What produces more crema when extracting espresso, darker or lighter roast?
2. What produces more crema when extracting espresso, finer or coarser coffee grind ?
3. why am I getting a very thin layer of crema when pulling a SINGLE shot, although the extraction time is 20 sec, the pressure is correct as per the manufacturer of the espresso machine (Breville Barista) I have, and the coffee beans were roasted two weeks ago?! what is wrong?

Comment: I feel like these questions have been asked a bunch of times before.
https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2867/what-factors-influence-crema-production-in-espresso
https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/9/what-factors-affect-espresso-crema

Comment: Have you tried some robusta beans?

Answer (score 3):

**The CO<sub>2</sub> stuck within coffee grounds produce the crema.** At least, it is the main substance that forms the crema along with other minor components.

This is a very classic problem -and thus a question.

- If you consider roasting, darker roasts have more crema as they contain more CO<sub>2</sub> as the product of [Maillard reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maillard_reaction). Here is a [proposed previous post to be read](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2172/quantifying-flavor-differences-between-varieties/2550#2550). You may also want to check [this previous post](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/3735/understanding-coffee-bean-names-as-they-relate-to-roast/3738#3738) as it may lead to more reading on other metrics you may consider.
- Grind has some effect, but limited. You may see the factors that effect crema production in espresso in this [proposed previous post to be read](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2867/what-factors-influence-crema-production-in-espresso).
- As you have mentioned, time has a crucial importance. I think this should be your main consideration and you should focus on fixing this first. Basically, **fresh coffee has more crema, always**. You can read a lot more [in this previous post](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/3323/how-long-does-it-take-coffee-beans-to-degas).